# How the data of Form.Item is propagated to its children component and whats the best way to define custom component for Form.Item in Antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

How the data of current Form.Item is propagated to its children component,
I have code something like --->

```
<Form.Item noStyle name={id}>
  <UserName/>
</Form.Item>
```

and it is defined like -->

```
const UserName = ({value = {}}) => {
  return (<span>{users.data.find(u => u.id === value).name}</span>);
};
```

Above code works fine… but my question is,
How can you define it instead of another Component inside same Form.item , for example something like --

```
<Form.Item
  style={{marginRight: '80px'}}
  name={id}
>
  ......
  ......
  ......
  ......
</Form.Item>
```